# How to remove gem from Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed a gem on my Rails application (devise). After I installed the gem, I realized that I don't need it.

I want to remove the gem, its dependencies and the files it created on my application. In other words, I want to restore the system to what it used to be before the gem. How can I do this? (I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Devise uses some generators to generate views and stuff it needs into your application. If you have run this generator, you can easily undo it with

```
rails destroy <name_of_generator>
```

The uninstallation of the gem works as described in the other posts.

Answer (score 116):

**You can use**

`gem uninstall <gem-name>`

Comment: Why are there so many upvotes on this one? The question is how to remove it from **RoR** application. And for that you just need to remove it from `Gemfile.rb` and `bundle` again. That's all. And for removing dependencies you have to delete associated files and dependencies.

Comment: And for new Rails applications, we can have the help of `irb` to save your system and work on somewhat virtual ruby version based environments.

Answer (score 48):

If you're using Rails 3+, remove the gem from the Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

If you're using Rails 2, hopefully you've put the declaration in config/environment.rb. If so, removing it from there and running `rake gems:install` should do the trick.

Comment: Will this also remove the files the gem created?

Comment: It typically doesn't add any files unless you explicitly specify, but it may modify some of the existing files, like routes.rb.

If you want to roll back those modifications, you can revert through the source control as @harald said.

Comment: Will this remove all the generators too?

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 4 - remove the gem name from `Gemfile` and then run `bundle install` in your terminal. Also restart the server afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
gem dependency devise --pipe | cut -d \  -f 1 | xargs gem uninstall -a
```

(this assumes that you're not using bundler - but I guess you're not since removing from your bundle gemspec would solve the problem)

Answer (score -3):

You are using some sort of revision control, right? Then it should be quite simple to restore to the commit before you added the gem, or revert the one where you added it if you have several revisions after that you wish to keep.

Comment: I am using git. Is there a way to restore my application with git?

Comment: Yep, look up 'git revert' or 'git reset' depending on your situation, one of those should probably help you.

Comment: This is clearly not the right answer. Using git or more generally VCS to remove installed gem or library is really crappy. Better use `gem-uninstall <gem name>` as suggested @rtfminc, or just remove the dependancy from the `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` in your app as @srdjan-pejic suggested.