# How to uninstall gem 'exception_handler' on my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, custom-error-pages, exceptionhandler

I used gem 'exception_handler' to  create custom error pages, but I need uninstall this gem and delete his content (views, controllers, all them)

Comment: check out other stackoverflow responses -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250362/how-to-remove-gem-from-ruby-on-rails-application

if it didn't automatically generate files, you might have to remove some manually.

Answer (score 0):

For uninstallation of gem use

```
gem uninstall <gem-name>
```

If more than one versions of gem present then

```
gem uninstall <gem-name> -v '<specify version>'
```

or if you want to not use that gem into your application then just remove that gem from your gemfile and run bundle install

For rails 3.1

To destroy a model use follwing syntax

```
rails destroy model <model_name>
```

To destroy controller use following syntax

```
rails destroy controller controller_name
```

and it will recursively deleted the view directory.